# Retrun a value from another component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

can someone explain to me how can I return a value from another component?

I tried the following:

```js
const ReturnText = () => {
  return 'Returend text'
}
    
export default ReturnText;
```

And i try to call it in Foo like this

```js
import ReturnText from '../ReturnText'
    
let someText;
const Foo = (props) => {
  someText = ReturnText()
  console.log(someText) // is shown as undefined in the debugger
}
```

But  when I try to log the `someText` variable I get `undifend`.

EDIT:

It seems the code above works. but maybe I oversimplified my issue:

Here is my actual code (that I thought is identical)

```js
import Geolocation from "react-native-geolocation-service";
    
let hasLocationPermission = true;
    
const LocateMe = () => {
  if (hasLocationPermission) {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log(position);
        return position;
      },
      (error) => {
        // See error code charts below.
        console.log(error.code, error.message);
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
    );
  }
}
    
export default LocateMe;
```

I try to call the LocateMe in Foo and assign the returned `position` to a variable (ant that variable gives me undefined)

Comment: I tried same code in react and I got "Returned text" in the console. link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-krdapz?file=index.tsx

Comment: Are you sure that import is correct? Where's the file? Maybe `import ReturnText from './ReturnText'`?

Comment: @Maharajan i might have oversimplified (see my EDIT in the question please)

Comment: `LocateMe` isn't returning a value. You're only trying to return a value from the async callback.

Comment: @masky007 i will try for updated code

Comment: @Andy But i also tried to set a variable outside the IF and than return it at the end (i assign that variable where i currently have `return position`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `getCurrentPosition` is an async process wrap the code [in a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and return that. It will resolve the promise with the data when the process is complete.

You can then decide if you want to use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) or a traditional [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to access the data when its returned.

```
function locateMe() {

  const config = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 };

  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
  
    function success(position) {
      res(position);
    }

    function error(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    }

    if (hasLocationPermission) {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, config);
    }

  });

}
```

Either async/await:

```
(async () => {
  const position = await locateMe();
  console.log(position);
})();
```

Or `then`:

```
locateMe().then(coords => console.log(coords));
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer how to assign the `locateMe().then(coords => console.log(coords));` to a variable, then console.log() that variable? (Your code above works though, i just can't figure out how to assign this to a variable)

Comment: [You have to structure your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) so that it takes into account the asynchronous nature of the promise. You can't define a variable, and then log it before the promise returns.

Comment: Ahh okay! I got it settled with useState like so `LocateMe().then(coords => setUserLocation(coords));`

Thank you!

Comment: Magic. Glad I could help @masky007.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the problem is here that you try to return from a callback function Geolocation.getCurrentPosition which will do nothing and it is expected.

The thing is, if an inner function call is asynchronous, then all the functions 'wrapping' this call must also be asynchronous to 'return' a response.

To get the value from LocateMe I would pass the callback function as a parameter like:

```
const LocateMe = (callback) =>
```

And instead of

```
return position
```

You do

```
callback(position)
```

And then in Foo, you get that value and do whatever you need to do with it.